# How to change transmission power in Inet 4.2

Tags: omnet++

How to change the transmission power of a wireless node in the Inet 4.2? Which class and functions code of the Inet should be changed?
For example, I want to change the transmission power dynamically increased 0.1mW per second in simulation time, as following:

- In simulation start time 2mW
- In 1th second simulation time, 2.1mW (When the simulation time=1 then TX power of the node should be 2.1 mW)
- In 2th second simulation time, 2.2mW
- and etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely, you can dynamically vary the transmission power as you wish.

In your .CC

First, locate your transmitter and introduce its name properly, getting its pointer as follows:

```
cModule * transmitter = getParentModule()->getSubmodule("ieee80211Nic2")->getSubmodule("radio")->getSubmodule("transmitter");
flatTransmitter = const_cast<FlatTransmitterBase *>(check_and_cast<const FlatTransmitterBase *>(transmitter));
```

(Remove or add getParentModule according to where your transmitter is placed)

Power transmission conversion to W from dB:

```
pt_w = pow(10.0, pt_dbm/10)/1000;
```

Change transmission power using FlatTransmitter object:

```
flatTransmitter->setPower(W(pt_w));
```

In your .H

```
double pt_dbm;

double pt_w;
```

Do not forget to include the FlatTransmitterBase.h header both in the .cc and .h:

```
#include "inet/physicallayer/base/packetlevel/FlatTransmitterBase.h"
```

Note that this procedure may be different if your version of OMNeT++ is different.

Comment: What are differences between Ieee80211DimensionalTransmitter vs FlatTransmitterBase? Thanks