# omnet++ change data rate in channel

Tags: c++, omnet++

I am new in `omnet++` , and I want to create a network of (say, n=4) nodes, where each node has an ingoing/outgoing bandwidth rate limit. Further, I want to be able to modify the per-link rates as the simulation progresses (but still satisfying the per-node constraint).

To my understanding, `omnet++` offers the `cDatarateChannel`, which includes the (protected) `datarate` variable, the `setDatarate()` function, and the `handleParameterChange()` functionality. However, I am not sure how to tie these together to create what I described above. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: hi, interesting, might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71572457/how-to-change-datarate-of-a-channel-during-simulation-in-inet4

Comment: @jspcal thanks for the reference, but I still don't understand how to *actually* change the datarate parameter in my C++ code. That is, what function should I call in my C++ code to change the datarate?

Comment: If you want to change a datarate just at the certain time, then I would use `ScenarioManager`, check [here](https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/users-guide/ch-scenario-scripting.html). If you want to change it dynamically, then you need to call a needed module and set a new value for the parameter in the same way as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69882285/12423880)